# How to fix net45 failing to load in a multi-targeted project?

Tags: .net, multitargeting

I cloned a repository from [GIT.hub](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing) and I'm having a hard time building this project.
Because it's a multi-target but it fails on net45, as shown below.

[image: Dependencies List]

I've searched and applied pretty much all solutions to install the .NET 4.5 and I can create projects in several frameworks, as the image below shows:

[image: Installed Frameworks]

But for some reason the net45 fails to load.

The pertinent configuration is as follows:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net35;net40;net45;net46;netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1;netcoreapp2.0;netcoreapp3.0;net5.0;net6.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I'm at my wit's end trying to solve this.

*Edited to add:*
In the comments, [user123456](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1682353/user123456) asked me what error message I was getting.
Well, here it is:

```text
error MSB3644: 
    The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.5 were not found. 
    To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) 
    for this framework version or retarget your application. 
    You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs 
    at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks
```

Comment: what error message are you getting ?

Comment: Run the Visual Studio Installer from the Start menu.  Modify > Individual Components > tick ".NET Framework 4.5 targeting pack".  Do pause a bit at the point of it, 4.5 went out of support 7 years ago.  The oldest relevant one is 4.6.2, due for the chopping block in 2027.

Comment: @HansPassant -- Tried your solution. No luck. For some reason my VS2022 refuses to load .NET 4.5

Answer (score 0):

What finally fixed for me was to install [Visual Studio 2017](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/), and select all the .NET Framework options, only those.